# Passing variables into command line arguments

Tags: rust

I am trying to pass a variable as a part of a bash command in my Rust program.

```
let path : String = "/home/directory/".to_string();
let  _command = Command::new("/bin/bash")
                  .arg("-c")
                  .arg("mv somefile.txt $path")
                  .stdout(Stdio::piped())
                  .spawn()
                  .expect("Cannot be executed")
                  .wait();
```

This program compiles correctly but the designated variable `$path` under `Command::new()` is not identical to the string variable provided above. Would like to know how to pass variables from the Rust environment directly into the argument.

Answer (score 4):

`$path` as written would be a *shell* or *environment variable*. You can pass Rust variables with `arg`. The easiest and safest way to do this is to get rid of the `bash -c` invocation and call `mv` directly. Then you can pass `&path` as a separate argument:

```
let path = "/home/directory/".to_string();
let exit_code = Command::new("mv")
    .arg("somefile.txt")
    .arg(&path)
    .spawn()
    .expect("Cannot be executed")
    .wait()
    .expect("Wait failed");
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c3de57eae952aa2fb2e5cda30f72223f)</sup>

If you did need the explicit shell invocation for some reason, the naïve approach might be to use manual string building, say with `format!`, to build a shell command:

```
// Unsafe! Do not build commands by hand.
let exit_code = Command::new("sh")
    .arg("-c")
    .arg(&format!("mv somefile.txt {path}"))
    ...
```

Don't do that! It is unsafe in the same way that building SQL strings by hand leads to SQL injection vulnerabilities. If `path` were a file name with spaces it would be split into several file names. Worse, an attacker could inject a path like `; rm -rf /` and wipe out your server.

The safe way to pass arguments is still using separate `arg` invocations. The trick is to reference them as `"$1"`, `"$2"`, etc., in the shell command. This method ensures that spaces, quotes, and other tricky characters won't cause problems.

```
let exit_code = Command::new("sh")
    .arg("-c")
    .arg("mv somefile.txt \"$1\"")
    .arg("sh") // $0
    .arg(&path) // $1
    .spawn()
    .expect("Cannot be executed")
    .wait()
    .expect("Wait failed");
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=97dbabba7fedcf6b11f8d29d72073b31)</sup>

---

Also, don't use `let _command =`. That would assign the final `Result` to a variable without checking whether it was successful or not. It's a good habit to always check `Result`s. You can see I added a second `expect` call in both of the snippets above.

But then, calling `unwrap` and `expect` too often is another bad habit. Whenever possible you should aim to propagate errors. The `?` operator makes this easy. It's shorter and nicer for callers:

```
fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let path = "/home/directory/".to_string();
    let exit_code = Command::new("mv")
        .arg("somefile.txt")
        .arg(&path)
        .spawn()?
        .wait()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0ed8e898f49bcd337f0ab8be6f8cdf22)</sup>

Comment: Either that or use `format!(..)`; but that would probably be a lot more error prone. *remembers sql exploits*

Comment: Do you have any idea on how can a similar exercise be followed on the Windows cmd shell? Like given a string argument how do we pass them instead of  \"$1\".

Comment: I don't know Windows, sorry. If `mv` is the command you're really using and not just an example, ditch the command line and call [`std::fs::rename`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.rename.html). That'll be portable across operating systems.